# Django ImageField upload to nfs. (No locks available)

Tags: django, upload, nfs, imagefield

I want to upload with a Django ImageField to a nfs storage but I get this error:

[Errno 37] No locks available

This is in /etc/fstab/:

173.203.221.112:/home/user/project/media/uploads/ /home/user/project/media/uploads nfs rw,bg,hard,lock,intr,tcp,vers=3,wsize=8192,rsize=8192 0 0

I also tried to patch django to use flock() instead of lockf() but still not working.

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9400

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: I think these discussions may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36154362/320399 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292365/320399

Answer (score 2):

I have this messy issue once, and after losing a lot of time looking for an answer I found this solution: `rpc.statd`

I have to execute that command in **both sides** of the NFS folders, in my case was my **Computer** and a **Virtual Machine**

Some information about this command can be found here:

- [Linux command: rpc.statd - NSM status monitor](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_rpc.statd.htm)

---

In case that is not enough, some times I faced this issue I have to execute the statd service manually because it wasn't running. This other way to fix the problem is execute in **both** sides of the NFS the command:

```
service statd start
```

After executing the command in **both** sides the locking problem should dissappear.

Some more information on NFS software can be found here:

- [Archlinux wiki: NFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS)

Answer (score 0):

You could check if nfslock is running on both the nfs server and client machines. It is responsible for managing the locks.